# Ubuntu 12.04 High CPU usage on Amazon EC2 Small instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, cpu-usage

I am running a small instance on Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I have also setup Cloudwatch Alarm on the instance.

The problem is that CPU utilization goes above 90% sometimes and I get notification alarm for that.
I have set a cronjob on instance which runs at every minute and stores the top 3 running processes based on highest CPU usage in a log file. Cronjob is as below.

```
* * * * * ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers | sort -n -r | head -3 | perl -pe 'print scalar(localtime()), " ";' >> ps_log/log
```

But I can't see any process with high CPU usage when I run this command on cron log.

```
cat ps_log/log | sort -k 6 -n -r | head -10
```

Following is the latest result of cron log.

```
Tue May 13 17:44:01 2014 17.1 10171 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 18:06:01 2014 15.1 10502 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 13:28:01 2014 14.7  6526 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 09:56:01 2014 12.4  3277 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 18:06:01 2014 11.4 10508 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Wed May 14 02:32:36 2014 11.0 16936 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 13:32:01 2014 10.3  6619 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 18:06:01 2014 10.2 10501 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 11:08:01 2014  9.6  4802 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Wed May 14 02:58:07 2014  8.5 17268 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
```

I can show the two Alarm results and the result of cronlog at which the Alarm notification came.

- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (96.72) was greater than or equal to the threshold (80.0).
- Timestamp:                  Tuesday 13 May, 2014 15:42:09 UTC

Cronlog:

```
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  2.0  8481 perl -pe print scalar(localtime()), " ";
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  1.6  8478 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  1.2  8004 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  1.7  8527 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  1.5  8547 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  0.9  8003 [httpd] <defunct>
Tue May 13 15:43:01 2014  6.0  8578 sort -n -r
Tue May 13 15:43:15 2014  5.0  8577 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:43:24 2014  3.3  8579 head -3
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  1.2  8527 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (96.72) was greater than or equal to the threshold (80.0).
- Timestamp:                  Tuesday 13 May, 2014 15:42:09 UTC

Cronlog:

```
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  2.0  8481 perl -pe print scalar(localtime()), " ";
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  1.6  8478 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:39:20 2014  1.2  8004 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  1.7  8527 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  1.5  8547 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:41:08 2014  0.9  8003 [httpd] <defunct>
Tue May 13 15:43:01 2014  6.0  8578 sort -n -r
Tue May 13 15:43:15 2014  5.0  8577 ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
Tue May 13 15:43:24 2014  3.3  8579 head -3
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  1.2  8527 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  0.7  8569 CRON
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  0.7  8501 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL -DPHP5 -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  1.2  8527 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin --user=nobody --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ip-10-178-52-49.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
Tue May 13 15:44:21 2014  0.7  8569 CRON
```

Now is there any way I can catch the process with high CPU usage? A website is hosted on the instance which has very low traffic.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. You may see a disconnect between reported cpu usage on linux in a
   virtual machine and what Amazon reports as the real cpu usage. Note
   that the latter is correct. Cpu usage stats monitoring via ps and top are
   unreliable, a good explanation resides here:

   http://www.axibase.com/cloud/2010/07/22/ec2-monitoring-the-case-of-stolen-cpu/
2. Regardless of the accuracy of the top and ps commands, something is
   causing cpu to spike. Ps and top should at least tell you which processes are using the most. Instead of calling ps once a minute which may
   miss the offending process, why not run it in a loop from a bash
   script with a short loop time (like every 10 seconds)? Redirect it
   to a log file and and you should be able to find a ps or top entry
   within a few seconds of the alarm. Something like this:

   ```
   while :
   do
     date
     echo
     ps -eo pcpu,pid,args --no-headers
     echo
     top -c -b -n 1
     echo
     sleep 10
   done
   ```